# Crystal report issue. How to display distinct record

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that looks like this.

> Title Header 1 : Title
>   Date 1 : Date
>   Date 2 : Date
>   List of Students :
>   Student 1
>   Student 2
>   Student 3
>   List of Subjects:
>   Subject 1

Is this possible?  At the moment Subject 1 is being displayed 3 times since there are 3 students.  How can I make Subject 1 to be displayed only once?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supress detail and group the report by subject and diaplay subject values in group header